# How to multiply each value in DataFrame series in incremental order using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataset `df` looks like this:

```
time                    Open
2017-01-01 00:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-01 01:00:00     5.2180
2017-01-01 02:00:00     5.2128
...., ....
2017-12-31 23:00:00     5.7388
```

The `df` above is an hourly series

What I want to do is `multiply` each `Open` value from `1` to `10` and then repeat it.

For example:

- The `1st value` is `multiplied` by `1`
- The `2nd value` is `multiplied` by `2`
- and so on until the `10th value` and then on the `11th value` we repeat with `1` and so on.

**What did I do?**

I came close to only multiply each value with the same number like this:

```
df['Open'] = df['Open'] * 1     # Number to multiply
```

but I am not able to iterate and calculate incrementally. I can do this in `Python` by putting an incremental `counter` and iterating over the values but how do I do with `Pandas`?

Comment: This would not work given the question. You should use @Quang Hoang's solution

Answer (score 3):

Maybe?

```
df['Open'] *= (np.arange(len(df)) % 10) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you!, what if I want to make sure that the `1st value` starts at `8 PM` so that it only starts multiplying from `8 PM` to next `10` values and then checks for next `8 PM` after the 10th calculation and `multiplies` next `10 values` and so on. Basically, it has to start at `8 PM`

Comment: @piRSquared what is `OP`?

Comment: You are. Original Poster

Comment: @floss your extended question is somewhat harder than this and deserve a different question/answer as it is not appropriate for comment.

Comment: I thought I would break it down to make it easier to understand who can solve the initial question :)

Comment: This actually does not work. This is the error: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead` The output result is also not correct.

Comment: That's because you're slicing your original dataframe. This solution answers **this** question just fine. It doesn't mean that you can apply it to a **slice** of another dataframe. See my comment in your other question.

Comment: I am not looking to slice another DataFrame. I just want to multiply a column `Open` incrementally from `1` to `10` and create a new column, let us say, `Open_multiply`. So the final DataFrame will have, `time`, `Open`, `Open_multiply`

Comment: The thing is, you have a dataframe with full date, then you slice a part of it (leaving out weekends). And you were trying to update this slice. Whereas you question didn't mention anything about your dataframe being a slice. Doing so trigger the error/warning above. What `copy` does is that it copies (duh) the slice to a new memory location, and hence the slice becomes an independent dataframe and no longer a slice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use index of the data frame, if its not pandas generated index , create one and try the code like below

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import pandas as pd
##Connecting to yaoo and getting the stock prices
msft_data=pdr.get_data_yahoo('MSFT','2019-06-18').reset_index()
msft_data['num']= (msft_data.index%10)+1
msft_data['new_high'] = (msft_data.High * msft_data.num)
msft_data
```