# Using Pandas how to multiply the values incrementally and take the summation of those values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

(`Not duplicate question`)

My dataset `df` looks like this:

```
time                    Open
2017-01-01 00:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-01 01:00:00     5.2180
2017-01-01 02:00:00     5.2128
...., ....
2017-12-31 23:00:00     5.7388
```

This is an `hourly` dataset.

I want to multiply the values in `+1` incremental order for 10 values and then take the `summation` of those values.

For example:

- The `1st value` is `multiplied` by `1`
- The `2nd value` is `multiplied` by `2`
- The `10th value` is multiplied by `10` and then on the `11th value` we repeat with `1` and so on.
- After that take the summation, `value1 + ... + value10`

**What did I do?**

I came close to only multiply each value with the same number like this:

```
df['Open_Multiply'] = df['Open'] * 1     # Number to multiply
```

but I am not able to iterate and calculate incrementally. I can do this in `Python` but not yet with `Pandas`.

> Once the `multiplication` is done, I want to store the `**summation**`
> of the `10` value in new `df` called `df2` so that we have `time` and
> `Open_Mult_Sum` in the `df2` `dataframe`
>
> (**SOLVED**) summation calculation: [Take the sum of every N rows in a pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239332/take-the-sum-of-every-n-rows-in-a-pandas-series)

Comment: same question again ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57099709/how-to-multiply-each-value-in-dataframe-series-in-incremental-order-using-pandas

Comment: @WeNYoBen That answer does not work, I already tried that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to multiply each value in DataFrame series in incremental order using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57099709/how-to-multiply-each-value-in-dataframe-series-in-incremental-order-using-pandas)

Comment: @floss if the answer doesn't work it's better explain so in comments rather than post again the same question.

Comment: @rpanai ok thank you, I will do that. The answer by rafaelc in this question is excellent. I only need to find the summation now.

Comment: @everyone: fyi (solved) summation calculation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239332/take-the-sum-of-every-n-rows-in-a-pandas-series

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `np.tile` and `np.arange` and then just multiply

```
df['Open'] * np.tile(np.arange(1,11), len(df))[:len(df)]
```

Comment: (SOLVED) Summation Calculation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239332/take-the-sum-of-every-n-rows-in-a-pandas-series